# Access Database Design of Month/Year for Budget Data

Tags: database, database-design, forms, ms-access, data-structures

I'm working on creating a database in Access for input of budget requests. What I want to do is create a form to allow users to input monthly budget forecast amounts that would be formatted like:

projectname ---month1amount --- month2amount --- month3amount ... for 12 months, then possibly yearly after that

The problem I have is that I don't know how to do this with my current table structure for the monthly information. It seems like a bad idea to create a table with hundreds of fields for each period, but that is the only way I can think of to input this in a horizontal manner.

The main table looks like

**tbl_Project**

```
project_id  
description  
budget_group  
phys_location  
expected_start <- Date  
expected_end  <- Date
```

The monthly table looks like

**tbl_monthly**

```
project_id  
monthly_id  
period(yyyymm)  
budget_amount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use that design, you won't be able to use the databinding in access.  Leave your form unbound, and then in the OnLoad event, query your tbl_monthly table to get all the records that should be displayed on the form.  Loop through them and set the values of the fields.  You will then have to run multiple update statements when it is time the save the changes.  You will also need to implement your own controls to select which project you are editing.